# how to view notification history for specific user in oneSignal with flutter

Tags: flutter, notifications, onesignal

I'm using one signal to send notifications to my flutter app and I can send notifications to specific users

but when I want to view notifications history all of the notifications are returned even the notification of the other users

what I did in flutter is that

```
  final http.Response response = await http
          .get('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications?app_id=appID',
        headers: {
        "Authorization": "Basic api",
        "include_player_ids": playerId,
      },
          )
```

how to make it display the notifications correctly of each user

Comment: u got any solution ?

Comment: I solve it from the backend.. It couldn't be done from flutter